# Replace String In Multiline Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace a string in a textbox but my code only searches the first line. Is there another function to use?

`Txtbox1.value = replace(Txtbox1.value, "test", "123"`)

Comment: Replace() replaces everything irrespective of the number of lines, something else is happening if that's not what your seeing.  Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: To me your code works. Make sure that the `(Name)` of your textbox is really **Txtbox1**. I tested your code on the UserForm where I have inserted a simple textbox and a button containing your code.

Comment: why don't you use if  `if me.txtbox1.value = "test" then me.txtbox1.value = "123"`    where and when you need to do this check?